# can't create draft using gmail api

Tags: java, gmail-api

I am using gmail api's for the first time. I am trying to save a draft message using gmail api.
The source code is similar to as follows,

```
String urlLink = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/" + emailSetting.getEmailId() + "/drafts?uploadType=media";
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlLink);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "message/rfc822");

        httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);

        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(message.toString());
        httpPost.setEntity(params);
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Over here message is the JSONObject which I am using to prepare the message json of as follows,

```
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject message =new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("threadId", 001);
        jsonObject.put("snippet", msg.getSubject());

        // Prepare Header start 
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

        jsonObj.put("name", "Delivered-To");
        jsonObj.put("value", msg.getTo());
        jsonArray.put(jsonObj);

        jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put("name", "To");
        //jsonObj.put("value", "<"+msg.getTo()+">");
        jsonObj.put("value", msg.getTo());
        jsonArray.put(jsonObj);

        jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put("name", "From");
        jsonObj.put("value", emailSetting.getEmailId());
        jsonArray.put(jsonObj);

        jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put("name", "Subject");
        jsonObj.put("value", msg.getSubject());
        jsonArray.put(jsonObj);

        jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put("name", "Date");
        jsonObj.put("value", new java.util.Date());
        jsonArray.put(jsonObj);

        JSONObject headerJSONObject = new JSONObject();
        headerJSONObject.put("headers", jsonArray);

        jsonObject.put("payload", headerJSONObject);


        message.put("message", jsonObject);
        message.put("id", msg.getMessageId());
```

The code above gets executed with status 200. But the draft message is empty i.e. there is no subject, no "to", and no body. If anyone has any suggestion to this source code then please share, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [Users.drafts: create from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/create). If you haven't tried yet.

> Creates a new draft with the `DRAFT` label. [Try it now](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/create#try-it) or [see an
>   example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/create#examples).
>
> This method supports an **/upload** URI and accepts uploaded media
>   with the following characteristics:
>
> - **Maximum file size:** 35MB
> - **Accepted Media MIME types:** `message/rfc822`

Here is a sample [java code provided in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/create#examples).

```
import com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Draft;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

// ...

public class MyClass {

  // ...

  /**
   * Create draft email.
   *
   * @param service Authorized Gmail API instance.
   * @param userId User's email address. The special value "me"
   * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
   * @param email MimeMessage used as email within Draft.
   * @return Created Draft.
   * @throws MessagingException
   * @throws IOException
   */
  public static Draft createDraft(Gmail service, String userId, MimeMessage email)
      throws MessagingException, IOException {
    Message message = createMessageWithEmail(email);
    Draft draft = new Draft();
    draft.setMessage(message);
    draft = service.users().drafts().create(userId, draft).execute();

    System.out.println("draft id: " + draft.getId());
    System.out.println(draft.toPrettyString());
    return draft;
  }

  /**
   * Create a Message from an email
   *
   * @param email Email to be set to raw of message
   * @return Message containing base64url encoded email.
   * @throws IOException
   * @throws MessagingException
   */
  public static Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage email)
      throws MessagingException, IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    email.writeTo(baos);
    String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(baos.toByteArray());
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
    return message;
  }

  // ...

}
```